# Implementing style chained select boxes in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I've been trying to implementing style chained select boxes in PHP for way too long, and I don't really understand what's going wrong. Here are the files: http://cl.ly/3j002v1E3s3G0c2O2B1M (there are many files, sorry for sending a link).

The select boxes just disappear when selecting the first one.

Can someone tell me why isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: You should provide us with more information on your problem (and change the title) o.w. a moderator will close this question very soon

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know what the problem is. When changing the select box, they both disappear. And no, it isn't a virus.

Comment: Maybe describe the programming language (`HTML/JS`?) in the title. Also what exactly the problem is. When I go to that page everything works for me

Comment: You fail to specify what your trying to make it do vs what's not working.

Comment: Basically I want for the user to be able to change one text box, and depending on that value change the values for the next select box. e.g. they select fruits in the first box, the values for the second box change to banana, orange and apple. I've tried so many different ways of doing this, which work, but then when trying to apply a style to them it breaks it. On this method (for me) when changing the first select box, they both disappear. This one is using php for the changing of values and jquery for the styling.

Comment: @TheoWindebank maybe edit that into the question

Comment: @TheoWindebank also I am not seeing any text boxes

Comment: Oops I meant select box, and ok.

Comment: @TheoWindebank finally one last word of wisdom since you are new: when replying to someone in the comment section, type `@TheoWindebank` at the beginning so they are notified (not necessary for the guy who created the question/answer)

Answer (score 3):

Your drop downs disappear because of

```
$('select[name="firmware"]').parent().remove();
```

The `.parent()` of your `select` is `<div id="formcontainer">` which is the container of your drop down selects; so your removing that element from the page which in turns remove them.

---

**Edit**
If your trying to remove the options from the firmware dropdown when you select a different phone then use

```
$('select[name="firmware"] option').remove();
```

or

```
$('select[name="firmware"]').empty();
```

---

**Edit 2**
It doesn't appear your populating the firmware dropdown correctly from the data returned from the ajax call also, you can use

```
$('select[name="firmware"]').html(data);
```

or

```
$('select[name="firmware"]').append(data);
```

If you are just returning the option html code back from your ajax call like so

```
<option value="1.0">1.0</option>
<option value="2.0">2.0</option>
```

But the demo page for the selectBox plugin suggest something more along the lines of

```
$('select[name="firmware"]').selectBox('options', {
    'Opt Group 1': {
        '1': 'Value 1',
        '2': 'Value 2',
        '3': 'Value 3',
        '4': 'Value 4',
        '5': 'Value 5'
    },
    'Opt Group 2': {
        '6': 'Value 6',
        '7': 'Value 7',
        '8': 'Value 8',
        '9': 'Value 9',
        '10': 'Value 10'
    },
    'Opt Group 3': {
        '11': 'Value 11',
        '12': 'Value 12',
        '13': 'Value 13',
        '14': 'Value 14',
        '15': 'Value 15'
    }
});
```

So if you return your data in the format

```
{
    'Opt Group 1': {
        '1': 'Value 1',
        '2': 'Value 2',
        '3': 'Value 3',
        '4': 'Value 4',
        '5': 'Value 5'
    }
}
```

You can then do `$('select[name="firmware"]').selectBox('options', data);`

---

**The Conclusion**

Basically if your `findFormware.php` code returns just option html code and nothing else like so

```
<option value="1.0">1.0</option>
<option value="2.0">2.0</option>
```

Your javascript code for the phone dropdown should be

```
$('select[name="phone"]').change(function(){
    var phoneId = this.value;

    $('select[name="firmware"]').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: "findFirmware.php?phone=" + phoneId,
        success: function(data) { 
            $('select[name="firmware"]').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, how didn't I notice that.. Thanks. The values don't seem to change though :/

Comment: The values to firmware through the ajax call?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure what I'm doing now. When I select it, a blank one appears and none of the options change.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying but how would I implement this into the existing code and does it work with styling? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your findFirmware.php needs to return just option html code back to the ajax call so that you may append that data to the drop down using the code in **Edit 2** of my answer

Comment: I updated my answer, it should contain everything you need to get your code working...

Comment: Okay I have put the $('select[name="phone"]').change(function(){... code in the document ready bit in the head but it doesn't style it. When I add $("select[name="firmware"]").selectBox('options', data); it doesn't do anything. I've fiddled around with it but I can't seem to get it to work with the styling